# How do I automatically add a calculation of difference of days?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Within a google spreadsheet I have 2 tabs, and im trying to automate the input as much as possible.

The date gets entered automatically in tab 1 when a row has info typed in, and a column with a  tickbox = true actions the row being moved from tab 1 to tab 2.

Within tab 2, I have the info being copied over with 2 additional columns - the date it was moved over and then a column that calculates the difference in days from date 1 in tab 1 and date 2 in tab 2.

The script works fine for most of the actions except for the calculation of days

I'm using the following script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  var ss = e.source;
  var tickedSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Restricted soon"); // Name of the source sheet
  var verifiedSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified"); // Name of the destination sheet

  var tickedRange = tickedSheet.getRange("C2:C"); // Assuming the tick boxes start from row 2 in column C
  var tickedValues = tickedRange.getValues();

  var targetRange = verifiedSheet.getRange(verifiedSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // Destination sheet will append rows at the bottom
  var currentDate = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < tickedValues.length; i++) {
    if (tickedValues[i][0] === true) { // Check if tick box is ticked
      var rowToMove = tickedSheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, tickedSheet.getLastColumn());
      rowToMove.copyTo(targetRange);

      // Set the date in column F in Sheet 2
      var targetDateCell = targetRange.offset(0, 5);
      targetDateCell.setValue(currentDate);

      tickedSheet.deleteRow(i + 2);
    }
  }

  // Check if the edited column is A and the row is not the header row
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var dateCell = sheet.getRange(row, 5);

    // Check if the date cell is empty before filling in the date
    if (dateCell.getValue() === "") {
      dateCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

    // Compare the date in column E with the date in column F and calculate the difference
    // Compare the date in column E with the date in column F and calculate the difference
    var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue());
    var endDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue());


    var difference = Math.floor((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // Difference in days


    // Set the calculated difference in column G of the "Verified" sheet
    verifiedSheet.getRange(verifiedSheet.getLastRow(), 7).setValue(difference);
  }
}
```

I get #NUM! errors with the above code. I've tried error handling like the below but I get blank cells when using this:

```
if (!isNaN(startDate) && !isNaN(endDate)) {
      var difference = Math.floor((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

The math equation seems to be the issue, I think its because the number calculated cannot be printed in google sheets?

Would appreciate any guidance from people rather than chatgpt, I am a beginner and trying to genuinely learn as much as possible. TIA

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sample spreadsheet with sample values so that we can try to replicate the behaviour and possibly create a solution?